# Count classified attributes using second series of attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, routing

I have:

- classified GPS-data them according to "Starting city - Destination city".
- a geodataset for German highways, that contains a `"Route-ID"` for each section.

Now I want to count how many times I drove over which `"Route-ID"` at which relation in QGIS.

For this, I joined the `"Route-ID"` per location and kept only one GPS-point per trip per `"Route-ID"`. So I want to count the GPS-points per Relation per `"Route-ID"`. Any suggestions?

The Dataset looks like:

[image: Example]

As example:
I drove 5 times from Cologne to Frankfurt and used 4 times the combination "A4" and "A45" but one time the "A3". On the way back i used the combination "A4" and "A45" 2 times and the "A3" 3 times. The result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Have I correctly understood that connections like `'München - Köln'` and `'Köln - München'` if they share the same `"Route-ID"` should be aggregated as one connection?

Comment: @Taras no, every Relation stands anlone. I edited the Question. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tested on QGIS 2.18

I can suggest using a `"Virtual Layer"` through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let us assume that we have such connections

[image: Example]

With the following Query, it is possible to achieve the result

```sql
SELECT Relation, Route_ID, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Dataset
GROUP BY Relation, Route_ID
ORDER BY count DESC
```

The output will look like

[image: Result]

---

**References:**

- [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: thanks! I had the same idea, just forgot to group also by Relation. Easier than thought.